# Effect of a matrix on determinant of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose we have some arbitrary square matrices $ A,B $ and $C$ of dimension *n*. We can find the determinant of their sum, i.e.
$$ y = \det(A+B+C) $$
My question is, how does the matrix $A$ effect the value of $y$? In other words, is it possible to know how much the value of $y$ will change w.r.t. to addition or removal of $A$.

My approach: I added $\phi_i$ (it is either 0 or 1) to the equation and tried to [differentiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative) it w.r.t. $\phi_i$.

$$
y = \det(\phi_A A + \phi_B B + \phi_C C)
$$
$$
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \phi_A} = \text{tr}(\text{adj}(y)A)
$$
But I am unable to proceed any further from this. I don't know whether this result is correct or am I going in the right direction. What should I do?

*Note:* Take *n* = 2 or 3. Keep it small.

Comment: $y$ is a number, not a matrix, so $\text{adj}(y)$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we may as well combine $B$ and $C$ in a single matrix, so we consider
$ y = \det(tA+B)$.  Then 
$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \det(tA+B) = \text{tr}(\text{adj}(tA+B)A) $$
When $tA+B$ is invertible, this is $$ \det(tA+B)\; \text{tr}\left((tA+B)^{-1} A\right)$$

Comment: This does not clear my question. First of all I don't want to combine $B$ and $C$, as I want to find their effect on $y$ too. Can I compare the effects of the matrices using the method I mentioned? Sorry for late reply, internet was cut off for 9 days at my region.

Comment: If you want to replace $B$ by $B+C$, go right ahead.
$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \det(tA+B+C) =  \text{tr}(\text{adj}(tA+B+C)A) =\det(tA+B+C)\; \text{tr}\left((tA+B+C)^{-1} A\right)$$
where for the last equation we assume $tA+B+C$ is invertible.